# Using firebase messaging in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to recieve notifications in my rails app and show them to the user (which accept to get notification)

I setup the client with

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Then

```
messaging.requestPermission().then(..)
```

I added "public/firebase-messaging-sw.js" and "public/manifest.json"

I can't get the message using "onMessage" but I want to get them in background

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your page is NOT open and NOT focused the SDK will send the background to the service worker in the Background.

If you open a window to a new website and then send a message do you see the notification?